# Can a Bundle reference MSIs from local folder during installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bundle, burn, wix3.7

I am creating a Bundle by chaining two MsiPackages. The Bundle incorporates the two MsiPackages and creates a bundled .exe as installer. Could the Bundle be set up so that it references the MSIs (not embed or contain them) from a local folder containing the two MSIs during installation? I would like to have the two MSIs referenced from local folder and installed only during installation.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. By default the `Bundle` element has the `Compressed` attribute set to `yes`. To get your packages external by default do the following:

```
<Bundle Compressed='no'>
```

All of your packages will now be external. Now if you'd like to explicitly compress only select packages add the `Compressed='yes'` attribute to the desired `XxxPackage` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't have a practical experience in doing this, I think you can try to use the [`Payload`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_payload.htm) element as child element of the [`MsiPackage`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msipackage.htm) element under the [`Chain`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_chain.htm) element to achieve this.

`Payload` element has the option to specify the MSI to bundle as `SourceFile` or `DownloadUri` attribute. There is an option to say whether you need to compress this MSI with your bootstrapper by the attribute `Compressed` which has a `YesNoDefaultType` value. By this you can specify your Source MSI without embedding to the package I hope.